# Is there static friction on the box?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram

I have the following problem I'm struggling to grasp

[image]

"A mass of 1 kg is on top of a conveyor belt that moves at a constant 1 m/s. The box isn't sliding. What's the absolute value of the friction?

The static friction coefficient is 0,6 and the dynamic one is 0,4"$$$$

Since there is no relative motion between surfaces, friction is static

I feel that since the belt is moving at constant speed, and the box moves at that same speed, it should be exerting no force on the box, and therefore there is no friction

Is this correct? If not, why?

Comment: Yep, you got it

Comment: Were there some answers and comments removed from this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set yourself in the frame of the belt, you see a static box on a static belt. This means that there is no horizontal force applied to the box. If there is not any other source of force (like, a force applied from air to a real box in a real belt), then the belt should not apply any force to the box.

Comment: The fact that the box is static does not mean there is no frictional force. A box resting on an inclined plane is a static box on a static surface, and yet there is a horizontal force that is resisted by friction. The conveyor belt in the picture *looks* horizontal, but it's not explicitly stated to be so, so I don't think the assumption of no force is warranted.

Comment: I assumed that the belt is orthogonal to gravity, indeed. If not, then the friction will be of a static nature and will be $\mid f_r \mid=cos(\theta)mg$ opposing the effective gravity force in the plane direction.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you are correct. Friction, static and kinetic, on an object parallel to a surface exists only in opposition to an external force acting on the object  parallel to the surface. There appears to be no external forces acting on the mass parallel to the surface of the  belt.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think the question should read "what is the *maximum possible* value of the frictional force?", rather than asking for the absolute value of the force. Note that we don't know anything about the orientation of the conveyor belt, so we cannot say that the frictional force is simply 0 even though there is no relative movement - if the conveyor belt is at an angle, lifting the box, the conveyor belt will be exerting a force on the box. All we can do is state the maximum possible force that could be exerted before slipping - there is no way to determine what the force actually is from the information given in the question.